# Cache Dependency custom key c#

Tags: c#

I use cache for data and I need to delete the cache for key when there are changes in the data. I want to use cacheDependency but it doesn't work. My code is:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("Key", cacheKey);

var keys = new[] {"Key"}; 

HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, item, new CacheDependency(null, keys), 
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minutesToExpire), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Can you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? The item isn't removed from the cache?

Comment: Not sure either what you are trying to achieve, you can hve a look at ChangeMonitor if you want to customise Dependency action however, the above question is not clear. You should provide a complete code.

Comment: I mean that does not delete the item from the cache, it does not detect the change.